# emacs meta key and Mint window manager

Tags: linux-mint, window-manager, key-mapping

First, I'm not sure what window manager is running on my Mint installation.  The "Control Center" yields no clues.  Nevertheless - whatever I have is grabbing the emacs "meta" key (the option key on my Mac) and dropping down a window menu.

Being a Mac person, I could do without *any* of those option key shortcuts into the menus.  Is there a way to turn them off completely?  Barring that, is there a way to at least tell the manager to listen for some obscure key, so that I can get my meta keystrokes into emacs?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to turn off this behavior in Terminal, which is sufficient: from Terminal's Edit menu, select Keyboard Shortcuts.  The topmost option is Enable Menu Access Keys.  Toggle this option OFF.

(Incidentally, **ControlCenter** > **Hardware** > **SystemInformation** > **OperatingSystem** > **CurrentSession** > **DesktopEnvironment** will tell you what window manager you're running!  If you really need to know... :-p)